Help Identify A TV Movie: Psychologist fell in love with his patient?
I watched a TV movie in the late 90s, a two-part TV movie which is set in period of art deco or the early twentieth century.
A rich young girl is having some problem and hired a psychologist to help her. He devoted a lot of time and finally healed her, and, in the process, they fell in love. As a result, he gets to be with her wherever she goes, including all the high life associated with her. In one scene, a friend commented on the shirt that he wore, he replied, "I only wear the best." (It does not portray him as a greedy man though, it is just that he starts to live in a life with his rich and pretty patient.)
Unfortunately, she found another guy and broke the relationship with him. He was in too deep, and still follows her and watches her with her new boyfriend from a distance. When the new guy cautioned it to her, she just replied, "Don’t worry, it's his job." (or something like that).
The ending scene is especially memorable: the close up of some leaves floating on the river, with a little bit of ripple or small waves bathed in the evening light.
The movie is set in a very tasteful mood, with a melancholic feel to it, very nice. I have only watched this once on TV, loved every bit of it, but remember nothing about its title nor names of any actors or the director. Would really appreciate if someone can lead me to find it. 
EDIT: 
The language is American English. 
The actors: None that I can identify with names. 
TV movie which is set in period of art deco or the early twentieth century, feel a little bit like The Great Gatsby.

Any details about the actors? Language? I assume U.S. English, but you know what they say about assuming.

sorry, i did not come back here after a period of not getting any answer or feedback. The language is American English. The actors-none that I can identify with names. TV movie which is set in period of art deco or the early twentieth century, feel a little bit like The Great Gatsby.

@travellersolo Is there any problem to log in with your previous ID?  Visit this  link. Continue with the previous account to claim your reputation.
